# How to linearize an expression involving derivatives?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, programming

I want to linearize the expression involving function $y(x,t)$
$$[y^3(y_x-y_{xxx})]_x$$

by assuming $y(x,t)=y_0(t)+y\prime(x,t)$, where $y\prime(x,t)$ is a small variation. In other words, I will drop terms involving multiplication of the small quantity or the derivatives of small quantity.

I noted [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26314/how-to-linearize-an-expression-automatically) helpful answer and came up with the following code

```
f[y_] = D[y^3*D[y - D[y, x, x], x], x]; 

((Series[f[y0[t] + \[Epsilon] dy[x, t]], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] // 
 Normal) /. \[Epsilon] -> 1) // FullSimplify
```

This code give zero. Obviously, there is something wrong here because the answer can be obtained easily by hand as follows

$$y_0^3(y_{xx}^\prime-y_{xxxx}^\prime)$$

However, for an expression without derivative this method works well, such as:

```
f[a1_, a2_] = a1^2 a2;
(Series[f[q1 + \[Epsilon] dq1, q2 + \[Epsilon] dq2], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] // Normal)/. \[Epsilon] -> 1
(* dq2 q1^2 + 2 dq1 q1 q2 + q1^2 q2 *)
```

**Update:**

With the concise answer from @Alexei Boulbitch, the original problem have been solved. This is an elegant method. In particular, it uses `eps` to indicated how many small variables have be multiplied in an individual term, then takes only the coefficient of `eps`, equlivant to expand upto first order. But it seems not a general method for linearization an expression. For example, the following simple fraction

$$f(m,n)=\frac{b-m}{a+n}$$

First, I used the original method including `Series`:

```
f[m_, n_]: = (b - m)/(a + n);
((Series[f[m0[t] + \[Epsilon] dm[x, t], n0[t] + \[Epsilon] dn[x, t]], 
{\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] //Normal) /. \[Epsilon] -> 1) // FullSimplify
(*(-dm[x, t] (a + n0[t]) + (b - m0[t]) (a - dn[x, t] + n0[t]))/(a + 
n0[t])^2*)
```

which gives the right linearization. As using @Alexei Boulbitch's method:

```
Lf = f[m0[t] + \[Epsilon] dm[x, t], n0[t] + \[Epsilon] dn[x, t]] // 
Expand; Coefficient[Lf, \[Epsilon]] // FullSimplify
(*-(dm[x, t]/(a + \[Epsilon] dn[x, t] + n0[t]))*)
```

It is inaccurate answer. But what is wrong with the `Expand` method?

My question is how I can fix my code to obtain the correct answer? Thank you!

Comment: Try using `Dt[]` instead of `D[]`.

Comment: @ J. M.♦ Thanks for your rapid response! Just try it with `f[y_] = Dt[y^3*Dt[y - Dt[y, x, x], x], x] `, which give a long and also wrong answer. `Dt[ ]` represent the total derivative but $f(x,t)$ is a function a two vars. Did I understand you, sorry if I made a silly mistake?

Comment: Have a look at the result of `Collect[Dt[y^3 Dt[y - Dt[y, x, x], x], x], y]`. Notice in particular the second term. Think about why the first term is the one that should be dropped.

Comment: @ J. M.♦ I noted that the second term of the `Collect` is actually the answer (after dropping the multiplication of small variables). I understand that the first term is a product of the derivatives of small vars so it should be dropped. However, I don't know how to drop it automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    f[y_] := D[y^3*D[y - D[y, x, x], x], x];

g = f[y0[x] + eps*z[x]] // Expand;
Coefficient[g, eps]
```

It returns the following:

[image]

Here `z` stays instead of your `y'`.

Have fun!

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch, your method works well in this case. However, it seems to be kinda not general :) Please check my update. Thanks!

Comment: @can  It is because you use it incorrectly. In simple function like in your second example, it is easier to take a partial derivative. In a more complex axample you in fact also calculate functional partial derivatives and, correspondingly, you need to use two independent parameters eps1 and eps2 for each of them. It is not a method I invented. One can read about it in the book: Smirnov, V. I. A Course of Higher Mathematics. 16 edn, Vol. 4 (Pergamon Press, 1964). It is the volume about variational analysis. Volume 4, I guess.

Comment: @can  Look, if you have a simple function, like `f[m,n]` in your second example, the task is trivial. `Series` works, you may simply calculate a partial derivative, and it also works, and there are still few other working  approaches. I would not spend time answering such a trivial question. A somewhat less trivial situation arises in the case of a functional expression including the one with derivatives, such as, for instance, that in your first example. In that case also I know also at least two methods of doing this, but, probably, there are more approaches.

Comment: @can Continuation, The point is that one should not think that there is a universal method valid for everything, but should apply to each problem the approach best suited for it. Have fun!