# How to linearize function of functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, nonlinear

From the [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26314/how-to-linearize-an-expression-automatically), I know how to linear a simple polynomial function of several independent variables.

For example, for two variables `a1=q1+eps*q1` and `a2=q2+eps*q2`, the function `f[a1_, a2_] = a1^2 a2` can be linearized by expanding in power series to first order with `Series`.

Now, I would like to linearize some functions of functions. For example, given a function `F` of two functions `g[x]` and `h[x]`:

```
F[g_, h_] = (1 - g[x]*h[x]*Log[g[x]/b])/(c*Log[g[x]/a] - d*Log[g[x]/b]);
```

For example, how do I linearize its first derivative and square?

```
dFdx[g_, h_] = D[F[g, h], x]; Fsquare[g_, h_] = F[g, h]^2;
```

The simple extension of the method in that link did not work.

```
(Series[dFdx[g0 + ϵ*dg, h0 + ϵ*dh], {ϵ, 0, 1}] // Normal) /. ϵ -> 1

(Series[Fsquare[g0 + ϵ*dg, h0 + ϵ*dh], {ϵ, 0, 1}] // Normal) /. ϵ -> 1
```

In the linearization, I need to eliminate any variable preceded by `ϵ` with power higher than `1` and any product of two variables preceded by `ϵ`. Thank you!

Comment: Do not set `\[Epsilon] -> 1`.  Instead, use ``Coefficient[%, \\[Epsilon]]`.

Comment: I would define `F` as a function that also takes the independent variable `x`. That can make tasks like this easier. And it's also good practice in terms of coding.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, did you mean to define `F[x_]=...` or `F[g_, h_, x_]=...`, I'm just confused by that "also" in your comment. Thank you!

Comment: By "also" I had in mind that latter, `F[g_,h_,x_]:=...`.

Answer (score 2):

**modified**

Assuming `g[x]-g0[x], h[x]-h0[x]`to be small of equal order try

```
Fx = D[F[g, h],x] /. {g -> (g0[#] + eps dg[#] &), h -> (h0[#] + eps dh[#] &)}   
Normal[Series[Fx, {eps, 0, 1}]] /. eps -> 1 /. { dg[x] -> g[x] - g0[x],dh[x] -> h[x] - h0[x]} // Simplify
(* lengthy output...*)



F2 = F[g, h]^2 /. {g -> (g0[#] + eps dg[#] &), h -> (h0[#] + eps dh[#] &)}  
Normal[Series[F2, {eps, 0, 1}]] /. eps -> 1 /. { dg[x] -> g[x] - g0[x], dh[x] -> h[x] - h0[x]} // Simplify

(* (1/((c Log[g0[x]/a] - d Log[g0[x]/b])^3))(-((
2 (c - d) (g[x] - g0[x]) (-1 + g0[x] h0[x] Log[g0[x]/b])^2)/
g0[x]) + (c Log[g0[x]/a] - d Log[g0[x]/b]) (-1 +g0[x] h0[x]Log[g0[x]/b])^2 + 
2 (c Log[g0[x]/a] - d Log[g0[x]/b]) (1 - g0[x] h0[x] Log[g0[x]/b]) (-((g[x] - g0[x]) h0[x]) - (g0[x] (h[x] - 2 h0[x]) + g[x] h0[x]) Log[g0[x]/b]))*)
```

Hope it's what you are looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing the terms "function" and "expression," which I used to struggle with. In strict, pedantic math, a function $f$ can be applied to an argument like $f(a)$ or $f(3)$; and an expression like $x^2$ cannot: $x^2(a)$ and $x^2(3)$ do not mean $a^2$ or $3^2$.  It does not help that in colloquial math, we say $x^2$ is a function and know what it means to evaluate it at $3$. Basic common sense and experience tell us that $x^2(3)$ is nonsense and not what the speaker meant and that they must mean to substitute $x=3$ into the expression $x^2$.

Likewise in Mathematica, there are two notions, function and expression, similar to the mathematical concepts. If an argument to `F[g_, h_]` is `g = g0+ε*dg`, then `g[x]` is `(g0+ε*dg)[x]`, which is nonsense, albeit syntactically correct nonsense. That it is syntactically acceptable to Mathematica does not imply there is any built-in meaning to it.  In the `g[x]` usage here, `g` is an expression being (mis)treated as a function.

One other thing before we get started. To linearize the derivative of a function requires the quadratic terms of the series expansion of the function.  This is different from taking the derivative of the linearization.  I assume the first is meant.

---

The first order of business then is to sort out whether you want `F[]` to operate on functions `g`, `h` or on expressions `g`, `h`.  Since the linked post operates on expressions, then let's do that.  As @DanielLichtblau said in the comments, it's best in this case to identify the independent variable that the expressions are functions of.

*An "expressional" approach:*

```
(* Better to use SetDelayed (:=) instead of Set (=)
   unless there is a specific reason not to.        *)
F // ClearAll;
F[g_, h_] := (1 - g*h*Log[g/b])/(c*Log[g/a] - d*Log[g/b]);

dFdx // ClearAll;
dFdx[g_, h_, x_] := D[F[g, h], x];
Fsquare // ClearAll;
Fsquare[g_, h_] := F[g, h]^2;
    
s1 = (Series[dFdx[
      g0 + ε*dg + ε^2/2*d2g, 
      h0 + ε*dh + ε^2/2*d2h, ε], {ε, 0, 1}] // 
    Normal) /. ε -> 1
s2 = (Series[Fsquare[g0 + ε*dg, h0 + ε*dh], {ε, 0, 1}] //
    Normal) /. ε -> 1
```

They have rather complicated output. If one wants to check the coefficients, then one could use `CoefficientList[lin, {dg, dh}]` or `Coefficient[lin, dg]` etc., where `lin` is one of the outputs.

*A functional approach:*

Here's a function-based approach in case that is desired or of interest.
We can redefine things as follows:

```
F // ClearAll;
F[g_, h_] =  Function[ x,
   (1 - g[x]*h[x]*Log[g[x]/b])/(c*Log[g[x]/a] - d*Log[g[x]/b])];

dFdx // ClearAll;
dFdx[g_, h_] = F[g, h]';
Fsquare // ClearAll;
Fsquare[g_, h_] = Function[x, F[g, h][x]^2];

sub = {g[x0] -> g0, g'[x0] -> dg, g''[x0] -> d2g,
       h[x0] -> h0, h'[x0] -> dh, h''[x0] -> d2h};
ss1 = (Series[dFdx[g, h][x0 + ε, {ε, 0, 1}] // 
    Normal) /. ε -> 1 /. sub
ss2 = (Series[Fsquare[g, h][x0 + ε], {ε, 0, 1}] // 
    Normal) /. ε -> 1 /. sub
```

Check both approaches give the same output:

```
s1 == ss1 // Simplify
s2 == ss2 // Simplify
(*
True
True
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand F around x==x0 you would write:

```
F[g_, h_] = (1 - g[x]*h[x]*Log[g[x]/b])/(c*Log[g[x]/a] - 
     d*Log[g[x]/b]);
Series[F[g, h], {x, x0, 1}] // Normal
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! it is the expansion of F, but how do I _linearize_ its first derivative and square?

Comment: Simple, instead of F in the expansion, you use F'. And for the square, you use F[..]^2